# Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\lVert f*g\rVert_p\le\lVert f\rVert_1\lVert g\rVert_p$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Simply stated, I wish to show that convolution behaves nicely with respect to norm, i.e. that for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\lVert f*g\rVert_p\le\lVert f\rVert_1\lVert g\rVert_p$. I can prove this for $p=1$, but when $p>1$, the power of $p$ seems to get in the way. So, how is this proved?

If this isn't true, then I wish to prove the weaker statement that for a mollifier $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\lVert\phi\rVert_1=1$ and $\phi\ge0$, we have $\lVert g*\phi\rVert_p\le\lVert g\rVert_p$.

Comment: You may want to use a stronger inequality for $p > 1$. How did you prove it for $p=1$?

Comment: See here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733782/why-is-a-convolution-of-an-l1-and-an-lp-functions-well-defined/1733883#1733883