# Why does $f,g \in L^1([\mathbb{T}])$ imply that $f \star g \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\mathbb{T} = [- \pi , \pi ]$. From a text on Harmonic Analysis:

[image]

**Question:** If $f, g \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ does not imply $fg \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, then how could we possibly have that

$$
f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{T}) \implies f \star g \in L^1(\mathbb{T}) ?
$$

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733782/why-is-a-convolution-of-an-l1-and-an-lp-functions-well-defined.

Comment: $\int_0^1 |\int_0^1 f(x)g(y-x)dx| dy \le \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |f(x)g(y-x)|dx dy= \|f\|_{L^1}\|g\|_{L^1}$